# iphone os 3.0 doc set

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, documentation

Does any one know the RSS feed for 3.0 iphone sdk doc set ?

I cant update the documentation from xcode.

Comment: FYI, here is a q-and-a with URLs for doc set later than version 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542614/download-xcode-4-2-documentation-for-offline-install

Answer (score 1):

Mine says this and it seems to work:

```
   Name: iPhone OS 3.1 Library.
   Identifier: com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.iPhoneLibrary.
   Copyright: Copyright © 2009 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.. Version: 22.20.
   Location: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.iPhoneLibrary.docset.
   Feed name: Apple iPhone OS 3.1. Feed
   URL: **http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.atom**.
   Web root URL: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/.
```

Comment: This is for 3.1. Is there something for 3.0 ?